# Product label printing application in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, label, jlabel, jtextcomponent

I am working on a personal project in order to learn Java. Basically its a swing application to print out product labels. I am planning to have 12 labels per sheet.

```
---------------------------------
|               |               |
---------------------------------
|               |               |
---------------------------------
|               |               |
---------------------------------
|               |               |
---------------------------------
```

I have designed the menu bars and and the tool bar. I was wondering what swing component I should use for the labels? Each label will hold the same product information and will hold a serial that will increment by 1.

Comment: how about a [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)?

Comment: You also need a gridbag layout

Comment: Does it need to be editable or is it display only?

Comment: It is display only but I will have a wizard window where the user can make font or font color changes that will reflected on all the labels. But the labels are not directly editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is display only, but I will have a wizard window where the user can make font or font color changes that will be reflected on all the labels.

Consider [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), which can render an adjustable, rectangular grid. Your wizard / editor can update a single [*cell renderer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), which knows the row and column number, and the class provides [*printing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#printing) support.